# Excel return columns with row containing certain values

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Nice easy problem i'm sure.

I want to be able to return a column of values from a list of columns where a row value is greater than 0. from the picture below you can see that column GX on row 5 is greater than 0 so i would like it to return x201 which is the corresponding identifier.

The columns span from F:ATE and the row where the number is is row 5. I am using this in conjunction with the solver function so the solution changes every time I input a new constraint so would like to be able to identify which columns actually have a result in them.

I have attached links to pictures to illustrate the problem and intended solution

Thanks

[Showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkCVD.png)

[image]

[Showing the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIYAG.png)

[image]

Comment: Easiest solution would be to transpose your range, so you can just filter your values, or use a pivot table to retrieve labels.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function find_1s(source As Range) As Variant()
Dim tmp()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
tmp = source.Value
j = LBound(tmp, 2)
For i = LBound(tmp, 2) To UBound(tmp, 2)
    If tmp(2, i) = 1 Then
        tmp(1, j) = tmp(1, i)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
For i = j To UBound(tmp, 2)
    tmp(1, i) = ""
Next i
find_1s = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(tmp)
End Function
```

[image]

Of course, a lot of parameters check must be added...

Comment: Thanks Akina, Looks good. does this code only work if the value is a one? for example if A3 was a 2 would it still pick up the value?

Comment: Also i get a value error when i input the code into visual basic

Comment: @matthewwilcox *i get a value error when i input the code into visual basic* Does you paste this code into a separate common (not worksheet or class) module? *does this code only work if the value is a one?* nothing prevents my code edition - you may alter checked value or transfer it into as a parameter (even as checking values array).